# Why is `rename database` command in MySQL considered as dangerous?

Tags: mysql, database

MySQL had a rename database command, however it was removed in later version because "use of this statement could result in loss of database contents, which is why it was removed".

Being curious about why it might be dangerous, I searched for relative discussions but have not found any. Please suggest why it is dangerous if you know the technical details, thank you!

[13.1.32. RENAME DATABASE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-database.html)

Comment: What's unclear about "*could result in loss of database contents*". That sounds pretty dangerous to me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: it's unclear why

Comment: hahaha sorry, i see the confusion.. "why it is dangerous" i was trying to ask what caused it to become dangerous, rather than why losing database content is dangerous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of bugs logged against that statement.

- [RENAME DATABASE destroys routines](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28360)
- [RENAME DATABASE destroys events](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17565)

So at least part of the problem was that it could destroy routines and events.

I find this note particularly interesting.

> I've modified the manual section to indicate that RENAME DATABASE
>   destroys stored routines and events.